# Select only items in a specific DIV using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use the HtmlAgilityPack to pull all of the links from a page that are contained within a div declared as `<div class='content'>` However, when I use the code below I simply get ALL links on the entire page.  This doesn't really make sense to me since I am calling SelectNodes from the sub-node I selected earlier (which when viewed in the debugger only shows the HTML from that specific div). So, it's like it's going back to the very root node every time I call SelectNodes.  The code I use is below:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(@"http://example.com");
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content']");
foreach(HtmlNode link in node.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.Value);
}
```

Is this the expected behavior? And if so, how do I get it to do what I'm expecting?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will work:

```
node.SelectNodes("a[@href]")
```

Also, you can do it in a single selector:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content']//a[@href]")
```

Also, note that `link.Value` isn't defined for `HtmlNode`, so your code doesn't compile.

Comment: This doesn't seem right with the XPath I know, but it works. I would also confess I used the HtmlAgilityPack for the first time just now, to answer the question. I can't find any documentation...

Comment: regarding link.Value, I was rewriting this from memory... it was prob InnerHtml or something.  So is the // making it always go back to root? I didn't get that impression from the XPath documentation on W3C

Comment: T​​​​​​​​​​​​​​hat's pretty impressive from memory... Anyway, you are right - XPath that starts with `//` should respect its context, as far as I know.

Comment: weird, kinda annoying it's not respecting the spec :(

Comment: i should imagine that the // calls back to root as I would surmise that even though you grab a node from the tree it still has reference to the whole document otherwise it would be impossible to reverse travers back up the tree with ..

Comment: Em getting this error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."