# Reading Html Code and finding <div> text. C#

Tags: c#

i am useing this code to read html pages :

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
            String htmlCode = client.DownloadString(@"C:\checkemails\check.html");
            // Replace all html breaks for line seperators.
            htmlCode = htmlCode.Replace("<br>", "\r\n");
            MessageBox.Show(htmlCode);
```

the html page is on C:\ but lets say i am loading yahoo.com.. or what ever page.

i need to find a div named who got the id of

```
<div id ="say">
```

how can i do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using [`HTMLAgilityPack`](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for this sort of thing...

for select item from a div see for example [Select only items in a specific DIV using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875347/select-only-items-in-a-specific-div-using-htmlagilitypack/2876384#2876384)

Comment: what using does i need for it?

Comment: it is a library - you can download it from codeplex, it comes with samples... just follow the first link in my answer.

Comment: stupid qustion. i have never used librays, where do i put it ?

Comment: Nver MIND! its works. the other thing you gave me isnt that good, any one have any other?

Comment: put it wherever you want - the only important thing is to be able to "add reference" the HamlAgilityPack.dll in your project (also set copy local to true) and then in your source you add `using HtmlAgilityPack;`

Comment: for more examples see http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/09/htmlagilitypack-article-series.html