# C# HtmlAgilityPack Select table from specific h2

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I have some html:

```
<h2>Results</h2>
 <div class="box">
 <table class="tFormat">
      <th>Head</th>
      <tr>1</tr>
 </table>
</div>

<h2>Grades</h2>
 <div class="box">
 <table class="tFormat">
      <th>Head</th>
      <tr>1</tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

I was wondering how would I get the table under "Results"

I've tried:

```
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");

        foreach (var o in nodes)
        {
            if (o.InnerText.Equals("Results"))
            {
                foreach (var c in o.SelectNodes("//table"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.InnerText);             
                }
            }
        }
```

It works but it also gets the table under Grades h2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the div is not hierarchically inside the header, so it doesn't make sense to look for it there.

This can work for you - it finds the next element after the title:

```
if (o.InnerText.Equals("Results"))
{
    var nextDiv = o.NextSibling;
    while (nextDiv != null && nextDiv.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Element)
        nextDiv = nextDiv.NextSibling;
    // nextDiv should be correct here.
}
```

You can also write a more specific xpath to find just that div:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[text()='Results']/following-sibling::div[1]");
```

Comment: As for `o.SelectNodes`: I'd expect it to work according to the dom hierarchic, but in fact it searches again in the root document - which is the reason you get the 2 `<div>`s. I saw that one before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875347/#comment2922368_2876384

Comment: Oh, if anyone wants to run the code, it is just missing a couple of lines: `HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); var doc = web.Load("http://jsbin.com/exegog/2");`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");

        if (nodes.FirstOrDefault()!=null)
        {
            var o=nodes.FirstOrDefault();
            if (o.InnerText.Equals("Results"))
            {
                foreach (var c in o.SelectNodes("//table"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.InnerText);             
                }
            }
        }
```